# Question about limit of an alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is a statement:

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a decreasing sequence ($a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ for each $n$) of positive numbers converging to zero. Then the alternating series $$ a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4  + \cdots $$ converges to a number *strictly* between $0$ and $a_1$.

What puzzles me is the final statement, namely that the limit is in $(0,a_1)$. I actually think it is perfectly possible for the limit of the alternating series to be exactly zero.

Consider $a_1 = a_2 = 1, a_3 = a_4 = \frac 12, a_5 = a_6 = \frac 13, \ldots$.

Namely $a_{2k} = \frac 1k = a_{2k-1}$ for each $k \geq 1$.

Thus for the partial sum $s_n = a_1 - a_2 + \ldots \pm a_n$ we can assert: if $n$ is odd then $s_n = a_n$ which goes to zero for large $n$. And if $n$ is even then $s_n = 0$. Thus the sequence of partial sums converges to zero, so the limit is exactly zero. This works, no?

As for the limit being strictly below $a_1$: intuitively this feels correct, but I have not been successful in proving it. I guess one could suppose $s_n \to a_1$, but I do not see how to produce a contradiction from this. Any hints?

In the case where $\{a_n\}$ is *strictly* decreasing, meaning $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for each $n$, then it is easy and I have managed to prove the limit lies strictly between $0$ and $a_1$. In the case where it is not necessarily strict, my example above seems to show the limit certainly can be zero. But I do suspect the limit must be strictly less than $a_1$, thought I cannot show it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Probably the author meant "strictly decreasing sequence", and then thought, "why doesn't this work for (non-strictly) decreasing sequences?", but then failed to think of your counter-example.

Comment: The upper bound $a_1$ isn‘t strict either: you can take your sequence and shift the index by 1, then $a_1= 1,a_2=\frac12,a_3=\frac12,a_4=\frac13,…$ is the counterexample.

Comment: brilliant, thanks guys